# Dynamicaly change the URL and id of a body via a link without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to dynamically change the URL displayed to the user and change the id of the body without refreshing the page. The function I require is very similar to flickr.com when you click on an image, the pop-up appears. The id of the body has a word appended to it, and the url of the website also has a word appended to it.

An example would be:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/orangeacid/459207903/
There is an image there, if you click on the image the URL changes to as follows:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/orangeacid/459207903/lightbox/
(This new page is just overlaying the old one)

Before clicking on the link the body tag is as follows:

document.body.className = [document.body.className, 'js'].join(' ');

...
After clicking on the picture it changes to:

document.body.className = [document.body.className, 'js'].join(' ');

...

Comment: can you please give us a visual example either code or a page?

Comment: I'm assuming you're just talking about changing a hash, in your url?

Comment: This is usually a bad idea: http://www.isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs

Answer (score 0):

Flickr uses Yahoo's [YUI library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/) and what you are talking about is the `lightbox` component, and the `history` utility.

There is no all-in-one function, you have to build it yourself, using the library.

Note about the url : HTML5 adds a new [history API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html) that allows javascript to change the url (`pushState`) without reloading the page and without using the "hash" hack. It's available in webkit (Chrome, Safari) since a while and in Firefox 4. Using history from YUI will help you implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started to repatch the jquery fancybox plugin to work with the History API. Which does something similar to flickr's implementation.

However, it might just be the history API you are talking about

[Click here to see my plugin on github](https://github.com/sydlawrence/fancy-box)

[Click here to see an introduction to the History API](http://sydlawrence.me/post/3014736805/history-api-demo)

[Click here to see my talk on the history API](http://sydlawrence.me/post/3315316563/my-heart-sole-talk)

:)

Hope it helps